# How to know if an anchor accepts withdraws from their stellar.toml?

Tags: anchor

When looking at an anchors stellar.toml files, how do we know that they allow withdraws and also what version of SEP it allows, either SEP 24 or SEP6 or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SEP-6 requires a `TRANSFER_SERVER` URL field in the stellar.toml, in SEP-24 it is named `TRANSFER_SERVER_SEP0024`. Both SEPs describe an */info* endpoint ([SEP-6 here](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0006.md#info), [SEP-24 here](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0024.md#info)), so you can presumably get all details at *https://[whichever-transfer-server-from-stellar.toml]/info*.